# C++ template explanation

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, partial-ordering

Could someone please explain me the below lines with respect to the "partial ordering" in C++ template --
"A template X is more specialized than a template Y if every argument list that matches the one specified by X also matches the one specified by Y, but not the other way around."

I could not get the meaning of this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I try to explain it with an example.

Look at the following `struct foo`

```
// generic
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct foo
 { };

// partial specialization
template <typename T2>
struct foo<int, T2>
 { };

// full specialization
template <>
struct foo<int, long>
 { };
```

There are three versions: a generic version, a partial specialization and a full specialization.

Consider the following argument lists

```
1) int, long
2) int, int
```

and observe the full and the partial specialization.

The list (1) match both specialization (with `T2` equal to `long`) when the list (2) match *only* the partial specialization.

Every argument list that match the full specialization (only the list (1)) match the partial specialization but exist a list that match the partial specialization (list (2)) that doesn't match the full specialization.

According to the lines that you cite, the full specialization is "more specialized" than the partial specialization.

You can also see that the partial specialization is "more specialized" than the generic version because every list that match the partial specialization, match also the generic version (with `T1` equal to `int`) but exist a list (`long, int`, by example) that match the generic version but doesn't match the partial specialization.

It's also obviuos that the full specialization is more specialized that the generic version.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Y
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct foo {};

// X
template <typename T>
struct foo<int, T> {};
```

> "A template X is more specialized than a template Y if every argument list that matches the one specified by X also matches the one specified by Y, but not the other way around."

```
// Imagine all possible argument lists for X. They will always match Y.
foo<int, int> f1;
foo<int, double> f2;
foo<int, my_object> f3;
/* ... */

// Imagine all possible argument lists for Y. They will not always match X.
foo<double, int> f4;
foo<int, double> f5;
foo<char, my_object> f6;
/* ... */
```

Hence, `X` is more specialized than `Y`.